# dcast / melt / reshape a table which has calculated columns in power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I have a table with 5 columns

```
Store ID | Year | Sales Group 1 | Sales Group 2 | Sales Group 3
```

All fields with `Sales Group` are calculated using DAX. I would like to create a new table which contains `Store ID`, `Year`, `Sales Group` and `Sales Value`. 
So essentially I would have 3 rows of data for each store ID and Year, each containing sales value for a different sales group

I want a DAX query to convert from Table 1 to Table 2

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

Comment: What is your issue then ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi How do I create a new table in that format using DAX, I am aware it can e done using pwoer query but my fields are calculated fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be better to do this in Power Query M, which has a built in unpivot transform, but you can get there with DAX:

```
UnpivotedTable =
// GROUPBY gives you unique combinations of the columns referenced
VAR StoreYears =
  GROUPBY (
    'Table',
    'Table'[Store ID],
    'Table'[Year]
  )
RETURN
// UNION does what it says on the label, unions multiple tables
UNION (
  // ADDCOLUMNS is also self-descriptive - takes a table, adds columns to it
  ADDCOLUMNS (
    StoreYears,
    // After the table arg, ADDCOLUMNS takes pairs of quoted column name and
    // DAX expression to evaluate for the value in that column. We create
    // two columns, the group and the sum of the source column for that group.
    "Sales Group", 1,
    "Sales Value", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales Group 1] ) )
  ),
  // repeat the pattern above per group
  ADDCOLUMNS (
    StoreYears,
    "Sales Group", 2,
    "Sales Value", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales Group 2] ) )
  ),
  ADDCOLUMNS (
    StoreYears,
    "Sales Group", 3,
    "Sales Value", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales Group 3] ) )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is in the Query Editor (Performance). Load your data, go to query editor and select the table.

Select the 3 columns of the sales group, go to Transform -> unpivot

Rename the column headers

End result:

[image]

Comment: I need to perform the function on columns that have been created using DAX they are dynamic in nature and are created from operations performed on several tables from the data model

Comment: I would consider doing that part also in M query, sure I do not know how big your dataset is so if you are happy with the DAX solution it is fine.

Comment: I agree with Aldert that the better place to do this is in M. DAX calculated columns are not dynamic. They are calculated once at model refresh time and then are static until the next refresh. If you mean the values change when you refresh the model, then any such calculation can as readily be done in M.